# Bizarre F# runtime error that happens in F#2 and not in F#3, also NUnit refuses to load an executable that runs

Tags: f#, nunit, f#-3.0

I have refactored a large F# project. It has an automated buildcommand that compiles all source files in one long run of the F# compiler. This is so that I can easily do reproducible builds. The buildcommand runs nunit-console on itself before building the project, and this passes just fine. After the refactoring, a large proportion of my unit tests started to fail with:

> *Exception: System.BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with 
>   an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)*

This is when the project is compiled with F# 2.0, and I can reproduce the same problem from the command line (i.e. without using NUnit). The stacktrace often points at an inocuous piece of new code (a constructor that just stores some data without doing anything obvious to it).

However, when the project is compiled using F# 3.0, all unit tests that suffer the problem under F# 2.0 and that I tried pass. This is when invoked from the command line (not using NUnit). NUnit now claims that the freshly compiled executable that I can invoke by hand just fine does not exist. There is a long stacktrace with file not found exception at the top. (I have not tried building the buildcommand using F# 3.0, so it's not surprising its unit tests are still fine).

Google suggests that HRESULT: 0x8007000B might be caused by a compiler bug. It may be a case of a bad crasftsman blaming his tools, but the issue disappears when F# 3.0 is used. Can someone please suggest anything to try to get things working again under F# 2.0?

I am not too troubled about using F# 3.0. But I really need NUnit to work. Does anyone know what could be going wrong? Just to reiterate, Nunit fails to load an executable that runs fine when started from the command line, yet loads the same executable fine from the same place when it was compiled using F# 2.0 rather than using F# 3.0.

I'll be really grateful for any help with this. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll also get this error message if you try to load a 32-bit assembly in a 64-bit process (or vice versa). What `Platform Target` are you compiling the projects with (set via the Build tab of the project properties pane)?

My guess is there's some mixup in your project settings or other configuration files which is causing the F# 2.0 compiler to compile it for the wrong platform target. When NUnit tries to load the assembly, it has a different 'bitness' than the NUnit assemblies -- which I believe have specific versions for 32- and 64-bit systems -- and ends up crashing.

Comment: I don't seem to specify one at all. However, I think this might not be it since some 80% of the unit tests still pass. And whatever it is, the whole thing gets compiled in one run of the compiler so it's not possible there is more than one conflicting platform. Plus it worked fine before the refactoring, and I did nothing to the buildsystem. Sorry for not mentioning all this earlier.It could be that the F# 3.0 version does not load in Nunit because there is some such mismatch. Any hints on what to try please?

Comment: This is the command line I use: 'c:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft F#/v4.0/Fsc.exe' -g --debug:full --tailcalls+ --target:exe --warn:4 --warnaserror:76 --LCID:1033 --utf8output --fullpaths --flaterrors --out:"..." --doc:"..." --lib:"..." --define:"DEBUG" --define:"TRACE" --reference:"FSharp.PowerPack.Parallel.Seq.dll" --reference:"nunit.framework.dll" --reference:"FsCheck.dll" --reference:"System.Xml.dll" --reference:"System.Xml.Linq.dll" (followed a large number of .fs files)

Comment: You could still have a conflicting target platform, even if the whole thing gets compiled in one run of the compiler (i.e., into a single assembly). The conflict would arise between your compiled assembly and NUnit -- if you have 64-bit NUnit on your machine and try to test a 32-bit assembly with it, it'll crash with a BadImagePlatformException when NUnit tries to load your assembly via Reflection.

Comment: In that command line, you're not specifying the target platform. You need to specify it like this: `--platform:x86`, `--platform:x64`, or `--platform:anycpu`. I'd suggest using AnyCPU unless you specifically need to target x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit).

Comment: I added --platform:anycpu It makes no difference, possibly because it's the default value when nothing is specified. Would you happen to know if there is a command line option to target an older version of .net? The GUI somehow manages it but the command-line help does not mention anything that would do something similar. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This smells like it might be a binding redirect issue.  When you invoke NUnit, do you just pass it the DLL/EXE, or do you pass it a .nunit file?  In either case, ensure there is a corresponding .config file with the same binding redirects that you get with a fresh ConsoleApplication project in VS2012 (e.g. the ones that redirect FSharp.Core 2.0.0.0 -> 4.3.0.0, as the powerpack depends on the former, whereas you have the latter on your VS2012 box).

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. There is indeed a warning suggesting that the mapping might be the problem when I use the GUI. However, the tests work in the GUI. (I am currently looking into fixing that even so.) However, the buildcommand compiles the project cleanly without any warnings at all (with both F#2 and F#3). Can the mapping still be a problem given the lack of warnings? Thanks again.